# Well-definedness of Fourier transform of $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ where the measure is taken to be the Lebesgue measure. The Fourier transform of $f$ is the function $\hat{f}$ defined as 
$$\hat{f}(\xi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\xi x}f(x)dx \qquad ,\xi\in \mathbb{R}$$
 Show that $\hat{f}$ is well-defined, that is, the integral exists (as a Lebesgue integral)

---

Can anyone check my attempt? I have mistaken somwhere but I couldn't find it. Thanks for your help.

Attempt: For any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $|e^{-i\xi x}f(x)|=|e^{-i\xi x}||f(x)|=|f(x)|$ ,and since $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, we get  $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|e^{-i\xi x}f(x)|dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx=C<\infty$$

But \begin{align*}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{f}(\xi)|d\xi  & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\xi x}f(x)dx\Big| d\xi \\ & \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big|e^{-i\xi x}f(x)\Big|dx d\xi \\ & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|C|dx d\xi=\frac{C}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}) d\xi=\infty
\end{align*}
where $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: the fourier transform of $L^1$-functions are in general $L^{\infty}$ functions. the fourier transforms of $L^{\infty}$-functions in general are not well defined. (see wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Fourier_transform_on_function_spaces)

Comment: to clarify: your attempt 1 is correct and suffices. the stuff you made after looks like you wanted to show that the double fourier is l1 (which i doubt) but this was not the question.

Comment: I supposed that the expression 'the integral' in the question is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}$ but now I see that it refers to the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\xi x}f(x)dx$, in fact, as desired :) Thanks!